# why *foo ++= *++foo may be undefined?

Tags: c, pointers, gcc

it should set the current character to next character. For example:

```
while( *foo ) { 
 if(baa(*foo)) *foo++ = *++foo;
  foo++;
}
```

But I get the following errors:

```
error: operation on ‘foo’ may be undefined [-Werror=sequence-point]
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

Can anyone explain why that? that isn't valid C syntax?

Comment: Search on SO first ("C sequence point" would be a good start). The error message says it all (or most of it): an object cannot be modified twice in the same sequence point in a well-defined manner. This is just how C is defined (or not-well-defined as the case may be).

Comment: I'm not a C programmer, but from the look of things, it looks exactly like what the error says, `*foo` doesn't have a value to it, i.e. `undefined`. You can't add something to something that doesn't exist.

Comment: You're incrementing 3 times inside the loop. Sure this is what you want?

Comment: @Hosh: there's no such thing as an `undefined` value in C

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could anyone explain these undefined behaviors (i = i++ + ++i , i = i++, etc...)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/could-anyone-explain-these-undefined-behaviors-i-i-i-i-i-etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's take a closer look at this expression:

```
*foo++ = *++foo
```

`*foo++` evaluates as `*(foo++)` (postfix `++` has higher precedence than unary `*`); you take the current value of `foo` and dereference it, and advance `foo` as a side effect.  `*++foo` evaluates as `*(++foo)` (both unary `*` and `++` have the same precedence, so they are applied left-to-right); you take the value of `foo + 1`, dereference the result, and then advance `foo` again as a side effect.  Then you assign the result of the second expression to the first.

The problem is that the exact order in which all of those side effects are applied (assignment, postincrement, and preincrement) is *unspecified*; the compiler is free to reorder those operations as it sees fit.  Because of this, expressions of the form `x++ = ++x` will give different results for different compilers, or for the same compiler with different compiler settings, or even based on the surrounding code.

The language standard explicitly calls this out as *undefined behavior* so that compiler implementors are free to handle the situation any way they see fit, with no requirement to try and do the "right thing" (whatever the "right thing" may be).  GCC obviously issues a diagnostic in this case, but they don't have to. For one thing, not all cases are so easy to detect as this.  Imagine a function like

```
void bar (int *a, int *b)
{
  *a++ = *++b;
}
```

Is this a problem?  Only if `a` and `b` point to the same thing, but if the caller is in a separate translation unit, there's no way to know that at compile time.

Comment: I think the example needs fixing to increment the int not the pointer. +1 for a good description.

Answer (score 6):

You're incrementing `foo` on both sides of the assignment, with no sequence points in between. That's not allowed; you can only modify a value once between sequence points.